How to useState + useEffect with DB data and charting library + useRef()
I have a useState with useEffect fetching the data from MySQL DB via "/charts" and with help of nivo charting library and useRef() I'm displaying single chart on the page. All good so far.
Now I'm thinking about improvement and displaying 6 to 9 charts on the same page sourcing it from different data (different windows of the same data) e.g. "/chart2", "/chart3" etc.
I could create 9 different useState + 9 different useEffect +  9 different + useRef() etc but it's what we have loops for right ? Can someone please recommend to beginner like myself, best way to approach this and let me know if this is solvable via loops ? If so maybe small sample.
My code below:
const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect ( () => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("/charts");
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            setData(jsonData);
            console.log(jsonData) 
          }
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    useEffect ( () => { //Another useEffect is needed to make sure on Browse refresh the page is loaded only after data is fetch from DB and then render
                if (data.length > 0){

                    const chart = createChart(chartContainer.current, {
                        layout: {
                            background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: "white" },
                        },
                        width: 600,
                        height: 300,
                    });

                    const newSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({ 
                            lineColor: '#2962FF',
                            topColor: '#2962FF',
                            bottomColor: 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)' });

                        newSeries.setData(data); 

                    chart.timeScale().fitContent();
                    return () => [chart.remove()];

                }
    },[data]);
   const chartContainer = useRef();
    return (
        <Grid container 
        spacing={0} 
        sx={{display: "flex", height:"100%"}} >
    
            <Grid sx={{height:"100%"}}>
                    <SiteBarCore />
            </Grid>
        <Grid sx={{height:"33%", padding:"5px"}}>
            <div ref={chartContainer} >
            </div>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )


I would create a component which is "GeneralChart" or something like that with the logic that is in common with all the pages. Then create a component with each chart for the routing (e.g. Chart1.tsx, ...), or create a single component doing e.g. <GeneralChart id={1}/><GeneralChart id={2}/>... if the only difference is a variable.
